# How to handle Alexa authentication and AcceptGrant directive

Tags: oauth-2.0, alexa-skills-kit

I am reading about creating a skill for a SmartHome API. From what I understood, Alexa first redirects a user to the "Web Authorization URI" specified in the Account Linking settings. After the user authentication, it receives an authorization code that should be exchanged for an access token. Then comes the confusing part.

Is Alexa then trying to exchange the authorization code for a pair of tokens in the AcceptGrant directive? If so, what should I do with the received tokens? Should I store them somewhere with another AWS service? How can I identify a user to which the token belongs? Should I do it using the [grantee.token](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-authorization.html#acceptgrant-directive-payload)? If this is the right approach, then for every subsequent request I should get the user id using the token from the request, get an access token assigned to this user id and try to receive data from my server using it. Please correct me if I am wrong. If this is right, then I do not see where the Access Token URI setting from the Account Linking settings is used.

I tried to look at examples from the developer documentation, but they all skip fully implementing the AcceptGrant directive. I also could not find any information on how this should be done.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer to your questions. About your first question, yes, if you are trying to use send Alexa Events permission, you need to exchange code using AcceptGrant directive, because AcceptGrant direct contains that code.

About your second question, yes, you can keep anywhere safely, it is not specifically under AWS environment.

I am sharing some useful links:

https://amazon.developer.forums.answerhub.com/articles/38610/alexa-debugging-account-linking.html

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/account-linking/configure-authorization-code-grant.html

About your last question, this is not correct, you would need to use grant.code, please see  the payload details for the AcceptGrant directive : https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/device-apis/alexa-authorization.html#acceptgrant-directive-payload

I hope this helps.